Expectation of Smallest Card in Half Deck
We are given a standard 52-card deck, where ace represents 1, jack represents 11, queen represents 12, and king represents 13. If we randomly shuffle this deck then split it into two decks of 26 cards, what is the expectation of the lowest card value in the left deck (obviously whether we choose the left or right deck here doesn't matter).
My original idea was to use indicator variables, i.e. have $$X_i = \begin{cases}
1, \text{ if the smallest card in left deck } \geq i, \\
0, \text{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$ Then $$\text{smallest card in left deck} = \sum_{i = 1}^{13} X_i.$$ Now we can use linearity of expectation to calculate $\mathbb{E}[\text{smallest card in left deck}]$. However, I'm not sure if my solution is correct or if there is another easier way to solve this problem.

Look good to me.  $E[X_i]=P(X_i=1)$ $=\frac{(56-4i)(55-4i)(54-4i)\cdots (31-4i)}{52\times 51\times 50 \times \cdots\times 27}$ giving an overall expectation of about $1.057345$

Hi Henry! That's what I got as well, but I was kind of hoping for a nicer closed form or some sort of summation identity that allows us to simply the expression.

This looks good to me, and I doubt it is faster to attempt to find a simplification than to do the calculation.
$E[X_i]=P(X_i=1)$ $=\frac{(56-4i)(55-4i)(54-4i)\cdots (31-4i)}{52\times 51\times 50 \times \cdots\times 27}$
and summing these with R gives an overall expectation of about $1.057345$.
selectionsize <- 26
EXi <- numeric(13)
for (i in 1:13){
  EXi[i] <- prod(57-4*i-(1:selectionsize))/prod(53-(1:selectionsize))
  }  
EXi
# [1] 1.000000e+00 5.522209e-02 2.076008e-03 4.679585e-05 5.125577e-07
# [6] 1.827300e-09 7.622220e-13 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
#[11] 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
sum(EXi)
# 1.057345

A simulation suggests this is reasonable
lowestleft <- function(cards, selectionsize){
  min(sample(cards, selectionsize))
  }
pack <- rep(1:13, each=4)
set.seed(2024)
sims <- replicate(10^4, lowestleft(pack, 26))
mean(sims)
# 1.058

which is close, allowing for simulation noise.
That was for dealing $26$ cards into the left sub-deck.  Slightly more generally, if you deal $k$ cards into the selection, then the expected minimum value card it has is $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{13} \prod\limits_{j=1}^k \frac{57-4i-j}{53-j}$$
and you can find this by changing selectionsize in the R code above.

What about a generalisation to splitting into k decks? Calling f(k) the expectation of the lowest card in a pile when splitting the deck into k piles, obviously we have f(1) = 1 and f(52) = 7, and you calculated f(2) ~= 1.057; what about other values of k?

@Stef It might allow more flexibility to say $k$ is the number of cards in the selection (selectionsize in the simulation) so $f(52)=1$ and $f(26)\approx 1.057$ and $f(1)=7$.  Then $f(k)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{13} \prod\limits_{j=1}^k \frac{57-4i-j}{53-j}$.  You get for example $f(2) \approx 4.804$ and $f(4) \approx 3.050$

Alternate simulation method: set.seed(2024);  mean(replicate(10^6, min(ceiling(sample(52, 26)/4)))) returns 1.057479
